# Dokku static site custom nginx config

Tags: nginx, dokku

I have a super-simple website that I've been serving as a static site with Dokku.

I recently realized that the default configuration for nginx on the dokku static buildpack makes all files available via a uri. I'd like to scope this down to just the files I need to serve the page.

I've created a custom `app-nginx.conf.sigil` file (see below), but it appears to be ignored by dokku on build.

All files are still available on the site and there are two lines in the dokku build output that make me think there is something wrong with my nginx config:

*FYI - the app name has been replaced with `<app-name>`*

```
$> git push dokku master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 305 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building <app-name> from herokuish...
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
-----> .static app detected
-----> Copy static files to www
-----> Reusing nginx binary from cache
-----> Using user provided app-nginx.conf.sigil
-----> Using default app-nginx.conf.sigil
-----> Using default mime.types
-----> Discovering process types
       Default types for  -> web
-----> Releasing <app-name> (dokku/<app-name>:latest)...
-----> Deploying <app-name> (dokku/<app-name>:latest)...
-----> Attempting to run scripts.dokku.predeploy from app.json (if defined)
-----> App Procfile file found (/home/dokku/<app-name>/DOKKU_PROCFILE)
-----> DOKKU_SCALE file found (/home/dokku/<app-name>/DOKKU_SCALE)
=====> web=1
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a file CHECKS.
       See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
       CHECKS file not found in container: Running simple container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
-----> Default container check successful!
-----> Running post-deploy
-----> Attempting to run scripts.dokku.postdeploy from app.json (if defined)
-----> Found previous container(s) (139a82449b6c) named <app-name>.web.1
=====> renaming container (139a82449b6c) <app-name>.web.1 to <app-name>.web.1.1485630818
=====> renaming container (37e990b5d729) mad_nobel to <app-name>.web.1
-----> Configuring <app-name>...(using built-in template)
-----> Creating https nginx.conf
-----> Running nginx-pre-reload
       Reloading nginx
-----> Setting config vars
       DOKKU_APP_RESTORE: 1
-----> Shutting down old containers in 60 seconds
=====> 139a82449b6c2642efb3a2f5706de93a2012003518461619ffdb37681c195906
=====> Application deployed:
       http://<app-name>
       https://<app-name>

To dokku@<app-name>:<app-name>
   f49a26d..90acc86  master -> master
```

The troublesome lines are of course:

```
-----> Using user provided app-nginx.conf.sigil
-----> Using default app-nginx.conf.sigil
```

And my `app-nginx.conf.sigil` file:

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log stderr;
pid nginx.pid;
daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include mime.types;
  server {
    listen {{ $.PORT }};
    server_name  _;
    {{ if ne $.NGINX_ROOT "" }}
      root /app/www/{{ $.NGINX_ROOT }};
    {{ else }}
      root /app/www;
    {{ end }}
    index index.html;

    location / {
      try_files /index.html /favicon.ico /logo.png;
    }

    location /css/ {
      try_files $uri;
    }
  }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do (restrict the server to only serve files I want it to)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want static site PAAS compatible with Dokku try https://github.com/pahaz/static-site-paas/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by updating Dokku - the issue was latent in a previous version. Definitely resolved by Dokku 0.8.0.